# Laravel - make database changes after PayPal Payment (securely)

Tags: javascript, php, laravel, paypal

Ok, so I've built a Laravel application which gives a paying customer access to content. I've tried Laravel Cashier and Stripe for weeks and it confuses the crap out of me, so I've gone for a far simpler option: a standard PayPal button.

My current solution is this:

1. User clicks PayPal button to process payment
2. I added some code to the Paypal button to initiate an XMLHttpRequest after the payment.
3. This XMLHttpRequest hits an endpoint which runs some code that makes a change to the database, hence allowing the user access to the content.

My question is this: Since the endpoint is visible in the source code, does this potentially mean this is not a secure solution? I'd figure it's less than 1 in 100 people who use this site would know to look in the source code, but potentially, since the endpoint is exposed, wouldn't it be possible to hit the endpoint manually and get access without paying?

If so, would CSRF protection prevent this?

Comment: Yes, if you're dispatching a request from the FE to indicate payment has been made, it is insecure. I don't see that a CSRF token would make this anymore secure, as that token only confirms that the request originated from the intended source.

Answer (score 1):

You don't specify what type of PayPal button you're using or show any code, but let's assume it's [a current JS SDK button](https://developer.paypal.com/docs/checkout/standard/integrate/)

Do not use actions.order.create() / actions.order.capture() to create orders on the client side and then later write the result to a database after payment completes. The client-side functions are only intended for very simple use cases, not what you are trying to do.

Instead, use the v2/checkout/orders API and make two routes (url paths) on your server, one for 'Create Order' and one for 'Capture Order'. You could use the (recently deprecated) Checkout-PHP-SDK for the routes' API calls to PayPal, or your own HTTPS implementation of first getting an access token and then doing the call with curl or similar. Both of these routes should return/output **only** JSON data (no HTML or text). Inside the 2nd route, when the capture API is successful you should verify the amount was correct and store its resulting payment details in your database (particularly `purchase_units[0].payments.captures[0].id`, which is the PayPal transaction ID) and perform any necessary business logic (such as reserving product or sending an email) immediately *before* forwarding return JSON to the frontend caller. In the event of an error forward the JSON details of it as well, since the frontend must handle such cases.

Pair those 2 routes with this frontend approval flow: https://developer.paypal.com/demo/checkout/#/pattern/server .  (If you need to send any additional data from the client to the server, such as an items array or selected options, add a `body` parameter to the fetch with a value that is a JSON string or object)